# display the matching content on array using php

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array `$arr`

```
 $arr =  Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => COURSE
                [1] => STUDREGNO
                [2] => STUDNAME
                [3] => FNAME
                [4] => SUBNAME1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => B.Ed. DEGREE EXAMINATION DECEMBER-2012
                [1] => 108023004
                [2] => RAMAKRISHNA REEMALI
                [4] => Personality Development
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => B.Ed. DEGREE EXAMINATION DECEMBER-2012
                [1] => 108027067
                [2] => RADHIKA NARABOINA
                [4] => English
            )

    )
```

how can I display the matching content in that array. if i have enter in one textbox register number.. how i am retrieving the particular result on in this array

Answer (score 0):

You need to use array_merge like this [Reference link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

```
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get matched values from array , use  [array_intersect();](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

Example:

```
 <?php 
 $ar1 = array  ('1','2','5');
 $ar2 = array  ('1','2','7');
 $ar3 = array  ('1','2','5');
 $result = array_intersect($ar1,$ar2,$ar3); 
 print_r($result);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tough I am not clear, but assuming this is what you want to do.

```
$main = $var[0];
unset($var[0]);
foreach ($var as $key => $vals) {
  foreach ($vals as $innerkey => $val) {
    $var[$key][$main[$innerkey]] = $val;
    unset($var[$key][$innerkey]);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [COURSE] => B.Ed. DEGREE EXAMINATION DECEMBER-2012
            [STUDREGNO] => 108023004
            [STUDNAME] => RAMAKRISHNA REEMALI
            [FNAME] => 
            [SUBNAME1] => Personality Development
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [COURSE] => B.Ed. DEGREE EXAMINATION DECEMBER-2012
            [STUDREGNO] => 108027067
            [STUDNAME] => RADHIKA NARABOINA
            [FNAME] => 
            [SUBNAME1] => English
        )

)
```

### Edited

Take a look at the variable names.
may be you need to replace `$var` by `$arr`